# How to import data drom dumpfile using import utility?

Tags: oracle, import, oracle11g

Someone gave me a dumpfile that I would like to import into one of my schema.
I have tried the following :

```
imp userid=system/pwd file=thedumpfile.dmp fromuser=sourceschema touser=destschema
```

But this only create the structure, all the tables are empty.

Am I missing something ? (the dumpfile do contains data)

Txs

Comment: Can you give an import log?
Can you run the import again? `imp userid=system/pwd log=logfile rows=Y file=thedumpfile.dmp fromuser=sourceschema touser=destschema` What are the quotas for tablespaces where tables are created?

Comment: Quotas attribution was the problem. Thanks for giving me the hint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the quota on the tablespace for the user of the table owner.